# ArgumentException when accessing Definition of a scheduled task (IRegisteredTask)

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I am trying to get information about an already existing scheduled task (using an Interop interface generated for taskschd.dll):

```
ITaskService ts = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
ts.Connect();

ITaskFolder tf = ts.GetFolder("\\");
var tasks = tf.GetTasks((int)_TASK_ENUM_FLAGS.TASK_ENUM_HIDDEN).Cast<IRegisteredTask>();
IRegisteredTask task = tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Path == "\\MyTask");
if (task != null) {
    var definition = task.Definition;
    // do stuff
}
```

This works very well on my tests on Windows 7 and 8.1 machines. However, when testing this on Windows 10, I sometimes get an exception when accessing the `Definition` property:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within expected range.
   at TaskScheduler.IRegisteredTask.get_Definition()
   at MyApp.MainForm..ctor()
```

On one machine, it is a HP system task that generates this error when queried. On another, it is a custom task that was created using the old `Win32_ScheduledJob` interface ([NetScheduleJobAdd](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetScheduleJobAdd.html)). (However, this same task can be successfully queried on Windows 7 and 8.1 machines.)

(The above code always runs as administrator.)

Is this a known bug in the Task Scheduler on Windows 10?

Comment: just curious if you navigate to the following using windows explorer `%LocalAppData%\Apps` do you have any folders or tmp files that may be related to the `MyTask`

Comment: @MethodMan No, nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

I also sometimes get an error when accessing the Definition property.

ArgumentException is a general error, as there aren't arguments involved in the variable assignment. I get a more specific error:

No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070534)

That occurs when the task is bound to an account that doesn't exist any more, so even asking with an admin account, the data can´t be retrieved as the account can't be validated.

Maybe that same error happens to you. The task you can get from a computer and can't from another might be because of that and not because of a problem with the task itself (or Windows). You can see if that's so by the log of the task, if the LastRun date tells you if it is actually running, or if it isn't working anymore (and therefore also inaccessible).